# Call virtual method in Mongoose when find() is executed

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I already created a virtual method like this in Mongoose Schema:

```
UserSchema.virtual('fullName').get(function() {
return this.firstName + ' ' + this.lastName;
}).set(function(replacedName) {
this.set(this.firstName, replacedName);
});
```

And execute find() method in server:

```
User.find({}).exec(function(error, users) {
// I want to use virtual method for users array
users.set('fullName', 'Name will be replaced');
});
```

Could I use virtual method for array without loop it?
I'm working on NodeJS and Mongoose.

Comment: I think it cannot because Mongoose Schema only apply for single object, not array objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like ***@truonghm*** said in comments, there is no way to apply in oneshot a virtual method to an array of documents.

What you can do:

---

**Loop**:

```
User.find({}).exec(function(error, users) {
   // Loop on results and execute the 'set' virtual method
   users.forEach(x => x.set('fullName', 'Name will be replaced'));
});
```

---

**Create a method in the schema that's gonna do the job for you**:

[Check the Query Helper part in mongoose Documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html)

It will result to:

```
User.getAllOverrideName(fullName)
  .exec(function(error, users) {

  });
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion about Query Helper part in Mongoose. I never know that before.